# nodejs app deployment with ZIP to Elastic BeanStalk => can't find local package

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

On Elastic Beanstalk, I would like to upload my Application using the zip feature rather than the EB CLI with command `eb deploy`

Unfortunately I get the following error where the server can't find a local module located in the subdirectory `./src/server/`.

***Thanks in advance for your advices***

```
> nodejs@0.0.1 start /var/app/current
> node www

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:983
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './src/server/app'
Require stack:
 1. /var/app/current/www
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:980:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:862:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1042:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/www:3:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/var/app/current/www' ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! nodejs@0.0.1 start: `node www`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the nodejs@0.0.1 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

**What I have done to experiment**

1. test `eb deploy` with my code=> succesfull
2. zip my code and load it in Elastic Beanstalk => failed
3. compare zip created from  step 1 & step 2 => can't find any differences

*code is always working fine on my local machine !*

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "nodejs",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "- [ExpressJS](https://expressjs.com/) ",
    "main": "gulp.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node www"
    },
    "author": "someone",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "^4.17.1"
    }
}
```

**www**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var {app} = require('./src/server/app');


var debug = require('debug')('testeb:server');
var http = require('http');

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);


var server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

**src/server/app.js**

```
var express=require("express")
const app=express()

app.get('/test',(req,res)=>{
    let t=new Date() +':'+ req.path
console.log(t)
    res.send("test OK : " + t )})

module.exports={
app
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without diving to far deep into the problem, try this
`zip app.zip -r * .[^.]* -x *.git* *.env*`

I had the same issue and this worked